# Error: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86

Tags: android, android-studio

While trying to create a simple math game in `android studio 2.3.1` after trying to execute my project, the app closes in emulator and gives warnings;

```
5-17 06:52:14.573 3088-3088/com.example.hp.game W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-17 06:52:14.744 3088-3088/com.example.hp.game W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hp.game-1/lib/x86
05-17 06:52:14.877 3088-3104/com.example.hp.game W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

And I tried solving the problem, but I do not understand why these warnings come up and **how to fix them!**

Comment: could you post your gradle scripts-> build.gradle(Module:app) settings? especially the block. e.g `ndk{  abiFilters 'x86'}`

Comment: I have same problem, did you solved it yet? #kuldeep

Answer (score 33):

You don't need to fix this as it is just a warning according to source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/arch/x86/instruction_set_features_x86.cc.

```
// Verify that variant is known.
bool known_variant = FindVariantInArray(x86_known_variants, arraysize(x86_known_variants),
                                          variant);
if (!known_variant && variant != "default") {
    LOG(WARNING) << "Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: " << variant;
}
```

The definition for `x86_known_variants` is

```
static constexpr const char* x86_known_variants[] = {
    "atom",
    "sandybridge",
    "silvermont",
    "kabylake",
};
```

If your emulators or devices are `x86_64` or `x86` you will see this warning which can be ignored.